# seleccionar, insertar datos en diferentes bases de datos

Tags: php

Necesito extraer datos de la base de datos 1 e insertarlos en la base de datos 2
pero soy nuevo en php y no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo.

les dejo el código de como están hechas las consultas a la base de datos .

```
include "db.php";

// Select records from database 1
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, apellido FROM empleados";
$result = mysqli_query($conn_1, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($conn_1));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["nombre"]. " " . $row["apellido"]. "<br>";
        
         //Insert records in database 2
$insert_query = "insert into empleados(nombre,apellido,email)
values('$id'].', $nombre].,$apellido)";

mysqli_query($conn_2,$insert_query);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
//mysqli_close($conn_1);
 //Insert records in database 2
// Create connection
?>
```

Comment: La consulta `$insert_query` tiene varios errores. Revisa eso cuidadosamente y seguro vas a poder solucionar tu problema. Pistas: como se concatena? donde estan los datos? las cadenas van entre comillas?. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Si el usuario que usas para conectar a MySQL tiene privilegios de seleccionar/insertar en ambas bases de datos puedes hacer una sola consulta, algo como esto:

```
INSERT INTO DBDestino.empleados (id, nombre, apellido, email) 
    SELECT id, nombre, apellido, email FROM DBOrigen.empleados;
```

### Observaciones muy importantes

- Esta consulta volcaría todos los registros de `DBOrigen`  en `DBDestino`. Se supone que debes cambiar ambos por los nombres reales de cada base de datos.
- La consulta podría fallar si ya existen datos en `DBDestino` por ejemplo, si existe un `id` ya duplicado y esa columna es llave primeria. O si hay una restricción `UNIQUE`  en alguna de las columnas y la misma es violada por los datos que se intenta ingresar.
- Esta consulta es útil si lo que se trata es de volcar todos los datos de una tabla en otra. O de volcar datos paraciales y **bien controlados** de una tabla en otra, mediante una cláusla `WHERE`.
- Si se trata de tablas muy grandes, con varios millones de registros, te aconsejo que hagas esta operación directamente en el servidor de base de datos, preferiblemente en línea de comandos, no en PHP. Y, espero que esta no sea una operación habitual, sino algo muy puntual de normalización o algo por el estilo.

Comment: _"Si el usuario que usas para conectar a MySQL tiene privilegios de seleccionar/insertar en ambas bases de datos"_ y si ambas están en el mismo servidor.

Comment: Correcto @Marcos. Ahora edito... Gracias.